# Power folding mirrors are 12 V (10 A fuse) and the wire is short. Should I add 12 gauge extension wire?

Tags: power-electronics, automotive, wire

Power folding mirrors are 12 V (10 A fuse) and the wire is short. Should I add 12 gauge extension wire?

The power folding mirrors' functionality works when the door unlock or locks which has a fuse of 20 A.

Which gauge should I select for extension of the 12 V wire of the power folding mirrors, or should I add relay? A short circuit happened that damaged the control box for the power folding mirrors when I was using remote start on the fob.

Comment: the question is better suited for https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/